# getting User_id from tweet using json module in python

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I use tweepy for streaming the tweets, and the code is..

```
def on_data(self, data ):  
   jsonData = json.loads(data)        
   id= jsonData["id"]        
   text = jsonData["text"]        
   createdAt = jsonData["created_at"]  
   ...
```

However the user id is contained within the user field. How do i access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easier to use `on_status(self, status)` method isntead of `on_data(self, raw_data)`. This way you process `status`, a `tweepy.models.Status` object, with user_id accessed as `status.user.id`, same applies for other user related properties.

If you wish to parse raw data manually, then use

```
user = jsonData['user']
user_id = user['id']
```

Comment: Thanks for the "on_status" method, was unaware of that. Appreciate the quick response!